# How to solve the problem of installing django-simple-history?

Tags: python, django, pip

In my project I need to use `django-simple-history` but when I run the command: `pip install django-simple-history` I got the ERROR:

> Could not build wheels for django-simple-history, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[image: See complete log]

Any solutions please, thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` (you may need to scroll to find it), with [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Next, [try to find a solution yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by copying and pasting an important part of the error message into a search engine.

Comment: What if you do the following:
`pip install wheel; pip install django-simple-history`?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have required Python and Django versions installed ( https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ).
Try to install earlier version of django-simple-history, for Windows:

```
py -m pip install django-simple-history=="3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if these steps could solve your problem.

1. Download the files from [**PyPI**](https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-history/#files)

2. Install the files using [**pip**](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages#installing-from-local-archives)

```
python -m pip install ./path/to/file
```

Last but not least, If you think that is a bug, please consider to submit the issue via [**Github**](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you disable the path length limit in Windows:

[image: Python Installation Screenshot]